# Drupal TCPDF does not create pdf

Tags: php, google-chrome, drupal-7, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF in Drupal 7. Following is my code:

```
function pdf_download($client_id)
{
    $styles[] = array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'media' => 'all',
        'data' => pdf_css_path(),
        'group' => CSS_DEFAULT,
        'every_page' => false,
        'weight' => 0,
        'preprocess' => false,
        'browsers' => array(),
    );
    $html1 = $html2 = drupal_get_css($styles);

    $booking = entity_load_single('booking_summary', $client_id);

    $booking_summary_info = booking_summary_details($booking, false);

    $html1 .= theme('space_booking_summary_pdf_pg1', array('info' => $booking_summary_info, 'order' => $booking));
    $html2 .= theme('space_booking_summary_pdf_pg2', array('info' => $booking_summary_info, 'order' => $booking));

    // Initialize pdf instance
    $tcpdf = tcpdf_get_instance();

    // Assign header and footer
    $tcpdf->DrupalInitialize(array(
        'footer' => array(
            'html' => '<div style="text-align: center;"><strong>This is a computer generated pdf.</strong></div>',
        ),
        'header' => array(
            'callback' => 'booking_summary_pdf_header',
        ),
    ));
    // Write html to pdf
    $tcpdf->writeHTML($html1, true, false, true, false, '');
    // add a page
    $tcpdf->AddPage();
    $tcpdf->writeHTML($html2, true, false, true, false, '');
    // reset pointer to the last page
    $tcpdf->lastPage();
    // Download pdf
    $bk_created = date('j F Y', $booking_summary_info['created']);
    $filename = "BK{$booking_summary_info['booking_id']}";
    $filename .= "_" . str_replace(' ', '_', $booking_summary_info['billing_user']['fullname']);
    $filename .= "_" . str_replace(' ', '_', $bk_created);
    // Supply a filename including the .pdf extension
    $filename = "{$filename}.pdf";

    // Change the path to whatever you like, even public:// will do or you could also make use of the private file system by using private://
    $uri = 'public://tmp/';
    $stream = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($uri);
    $path = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $stream->getDirectoryPath() . '/' . file_uri_target($uri);

    // Create the full path
    $full_path = "{$path}/{$filename}";
    $tcpdf->Output($full_path, 'I');
}
```

The same code generates a proper pdf when executed on the local machine but does not generate pdf on production. There is neither error present in Drupal logs nor in nginx logs.

The output in the chrome browser when executed on production looks something like the below image:

[image: No pdf present]

What could be the reason for such odd behavior?

**EDIT:** The above behavior is present only in Chrome. Other browsers render pdf file properly.

Comment: Try to add "Exit" at end  : `$tcpdf->Output($full_path, 'I'); exit;`

Comment: That didn't help... read my edit.

Comment: If you change download mode to dowloand only (without visualisation in browser) , you have a correct rendering into pdf or it's the same ?

Comment: If I change it to download mode, then the rendering is correct. I get a proper pdf.